# Как соединить Scale и Перо в Turtle

Tags: python, tkinter, turtle

Как сделать так, чтобы смотря какое выходит число из шкалы, изменяло размер пера ?

Вот код:

```
from turtle import *
from tkinter import *

shape('circle')

scale_widget3 = Scale(orient="horizontal", resolution=1, from_=0, to=10, bd=4, width=17)
scale_widget3.pack()

done()
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно привязать функцию, которая будет реагировать на изменение `scale` через параметр `command`. Внутри нее вызываете функцию `shapesize`, чтобы изменить размер пера:

```
def on_scale_change(size):
    shapesize(stretch_wid=size, stretch_len=size)


scale_widget3 = Scale(orient="horizontal", resolution=1, from_=1, to=10, bd=4, width=17, command=on_scale_change)
```